# Twitter.getApiClient(session) not found android

Tags: android, twitter

I need to get information from twitter login. I am able to login but while trying to fetch user information, (Twitter.getApiClient(session)) is not found in library. Please, tell me what I am doing wrong.

The used library and code is:

```
compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.0.0'
compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-mopub:3.0.0' 

public static void getResultTwitter(TwitterSession session){
Call<User> userResult =Twitter.getApiClient(session).getAccountService().verifyCredentials(true,false);
    userResult.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {

        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void success(Result<User> userResult) {

            User user = userResult.data;
            String twitterImage = user.profileImageUrl;

            try {
                Log.d("imageurl", user.profileImageUrl);
                Log.d("name", user.name);
                Log.d("email",user.email);
                Log.d("des", user.description);
                Log.d("followers ", String.valueOf(user.followersCount));
                Log.d("createdAt", user.createdAt);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

    });

}
```

Comment: I am facing same problem.. unresolve method getApiClient

Answer (score 1):

You can find the method at the following location.

```
TwitterCore.getInstance().getApiClient().getAccountService().verifyCredentials()
```

Answer (score 1):

You will find that in

```
TwitterCore.getInstance().getApiClient(twitterSession).getAccountService().verifyCredentials(false,true,false).enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void success(Result<User> userResult) {
            try {

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException e) {
        }
    });
```